# Function changes data of input array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an quiz app in react. Everything is working perfectly exept from a function that shuffles my array so the answers seem random every time. Here's the code.

```
  shuffleArray() {
    let array = this.state.answerArray;
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Fetching and storing is working, but anytime I call that shuffleArray function, my original array (answerArray) also shuffles exactly like shuffledArray.

Im calling function after setState after fetching my data

```
this.setState(
          {
            qid: _id,
            question: question,
            correct_answer: correct_answer,
            answerArray: [
              correct_answer,
              answer1 || " ",
              answer2 || " ",
              answer3 || " "
            ]
          },
          () => {
            this.setState({
              shuffledArray: this.shuffleArray()
            });
          }
        );
```

Any idea why do both arrays shuffle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look `shuffleArray` :

```
 shuffleArray() {
    let array = this.state.answerArray;
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }
```

This line here :

```
 let array = this.state.answerArray;
```

It is NOT copying the value of `this.state.answerArray` into `array`. `array` IS `this.state.answerArray`, so by modifying `array` you modify `this.state.answerArray`.

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy your array :

```
let array = [...this.state.answerArray];
```

But WHY ? You may  ask.

Well, Array are [mutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable) (so do object and functions), so assignement are made by reference, not copy.

What do I do if I have an array of object ?

[Check Josh answer below !](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60531390/4094323)

Comment: @F.Frlić you're welcome, Please take time to read links that are in my answer, you will earn valuable knowledge in Javascript and become able to help others in the future ! Also, do not forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating the array returned by React state, that's why. You should not do that - see [here](https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42).

Do this instead:

```
shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }
```

```
() => {
   this.setState({
    shuffledArray: this.shuffleArray([...this.state.answerArray])
  });
```

This assumes that your array is made up of primitives (numbers, strings). If it is made up of objects, you need to do this:

```
this.shuffleArray(this.state.answerArray.map(answer => {...answer}))
```

If those objects contain other objects, then you should deep clone it with [`_.cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep). This a method from the Lodash utility library that recursively clones objects to give you a true deep copy.

Arrays and objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. And React state is not cloned, you get a real reference to the state object.

You get the *actual* state object from React in your code so that React doesn't need to do a deep comparison of the state. It just needs to check the object reference.

If you are interested to know more about this, check out "[Avoiding global mutable state in Browser JS](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/avoid-global-state/)" and the section "Understanding Object References" in the article "[Shun the mutant - the case for const](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/)".

Comment: Hi Josh. Talking about made up object and deep cloning is a nice idea. May I suggest that you do talk about lodash as you are linking a method from the library in your answer ? You wouldn't want readers to think that it's a native javascript methods ^^

Comment: FYI, I linked your answer in mine if anyone need help on array made of objects ;)